# How to create a folder in wwwroot by coding?

Tags: asp.net-core, directory

How to create a folder in wwwroot by coding?
im use asp core 2.2
this code not working:
 Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "wwwroot\UploadFile");a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with below code sample :

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\UploadFile");
if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Path.Combine` will only give you the path string. It won't create a directory by itself.

I suggest passing `IHostingEnvironment` to your class through dependency injection and then using `WebRootPath` to get the path for wwwroot folder (i.e. not hardcoding it).

```cs
public class YourClass
{
   private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

   public YourClass(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       _env = env;
   }

   public YourMethod()
   {
       string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "UploadFile").ToLower();

       //if path does not exist -> create it
       if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   }
}
```

Comment: i use this code @ivan B and directory is created in phisycal root but not maped in visual sdudio and not show to wwwroot folder on the visual studio.

Comment: @AliRamezani Are you creating this folder so that to write files into it? Try creating file in that folder. In my project I create folder and then create new file in it. Then Visual Studio shows that new folder and file in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Try doing this: 
`string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, "myFile.txt");
using (StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
                {
                     fileStream.Write("Some text here");
                }
`
The `path` will be your path variable that you created from the code before